# ASR instruction not working for ARM9E platform

Tags: arm, inline-assembly

I want to perform an arithmetic right shift on data present in a register. I wrote this in my inline assembly:

`ASR acc0, acc0, #15`

However on compiling I get an error saying **Inline assembler syntax error**.

But when I used `MOV` instruction to perform the same operation it compiles fine.

`MOV acc0, acc0, ASR #15`

I can not understand what is the problem in using ASR instead of MOV? I am compiling this code for ARM9E platform.

Comment: What assembler are you using? Whatever it is, it obviously doesn't (or isn't configured to) accept the newer UAL assembly syntax (where ARM `asr` is merely an alias for `mov` - it's only an actual instruction in Thumb).

Comment: I am compiling using GCC toolchain for ARM.

Comment: With what version of binutils (i.e. the assembler)? The oldest thing I have to hand is a GCC 4.4.3 toolchain with binutils 2.19, and that accepts the UAL alias quite happily.